# Bug in html <marquee> style CSS animation

Tags: css

[Here is a short codepen](https://codepen.io/canovice/pen/WzOjJz) of a simple css animation that I'm struggling to work with. Code also below:

```css
.navscroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.navscroll div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: navscroll 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes navscroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navscroll">
  <div>Why arent these</div>
  <div>Side by side</div>
  <div>or sliding across the WHOLE navbar</div>
</div>
```

Its supposed to be a scrolling navbar of divs, but I'm having two issues:

- The inner divs are stacking vertically, not horizontally...
- The inner divs are scrolling across only a small percentage of the nav bar / outer div...

Ideally, if there were many divs in the navscroll div, only 5-6 of them would display anytime on the screen, although the navbar would always be scrolling and those other divs would make their way onto the screen eventually. (similar to stock tickers ticking across the top of the TV screen). Any help with this is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: how did you format my code into a snippet like that? thanks btw

Comment: @Canovice The snippet button is next to the picture attachment button in the editor bar.

Comment: @connexo by posting a lot of questions

Comment: Pick your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` is a block level element (means it has `display: block;` by default). These create a line break before and after themselves. Use `display: inline-block;` and make sure they align properly using `vertical-align: middle;`.

**2nd problem**: `translateX(100%)` here the percentage does not refer to the parent element, but to the `div` being animated.

```css
.navscroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navscroll div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: navscroll 15s linear infinite;
  /* this does the magic: */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@keyframes navscroll {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navscroll">
  <div>Why arent these</div>
  <div>Side by side</div>
  <div>or sliding across the WHOLE navbar</div>
</div>
```

As per your question about how to create a snippet here:

[image: Snippet button]

Comment: You don't address the whole problem stated in the question.

Comment: This addresses half of the problem though, which is a helpful start

Comment: The other half is adressed too, now. Might need more tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

The inner `div`s are stacking vertically because the default styling for a `div` is `display: block`. Adding the styles `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` to your `.navscroll div` rules will set them side by side, aligned to their top edges.

The animation is starting in the middle, and not all the way to the right like you intend because of how `transform: translate()` works. `transform` refers to the object being transformed, not its parent. So, translating something 100% of it refers to the width of the object. Try animating the position, something like this instead:

```
@keyframes navscroll {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -600px;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Also, remove the initial `transform: translateX(100%);` and you can simply animate the left position to -600px (3x the width of the each block).

Comment: It seems like I'd be better off animating the inner-divs themselves, and not the outer-div

Comment: Aren't you, though? You're calling the navscroll animation on the inner div (it's just called the same thing as the outer div, which might be confusing).

Comment: okay this is good yeah. my last question / thought is if I could compute what the best number for 100% is, rather than choosing -600px.

Comment: (width of all inner divs) * (number of inner divs) or something like that

Comment: If you know the number of divs and a fixed width, yes, you could do `left: calc( number-of-divs * width-of-div * -1 );`. I'm not sure if you can do it programmatically without SCSS or something. Also, of course take into account margin, padding, etc.